# Recording streaming audio track (m4v)

Tags: windows, audio, streaming, recording, ripping

I'd like to rip the audio track from [Joel's speech at Business on Software 2009](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2010/08/19.html), but didn't manage to find how to download the m4v file by looking through the log file when my browser plays the video.

Does someone know of an easy way to do this, preferable an open-source solution available on XP.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply go to [**http://blip.tv/file/3996778**](http://blip.tv/file/3996778) and right-click the **download** link near the bottom of the page.  This will give you the option to save the file into the m4v format.

You could then use something like [**Freemake Video Converter**](http://www.freemake.com/downloads/) or [**SUPER**](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html) to convert the m4v into mp3 or another audio-only format, if you wanted to.  These tools are not open source, but very free and both work on XP.  One caveat to Freemake is that you need the latest .net framework (automatically downloaded during installation), but it is still my preference.